# How do I upload a 50MB zipped xml file (with namespaces & full size 600MB) into a mysql table via shell/terminal

Tags: mysql, xml, shell, terminal

How do I upload a 50MB zip file with a 600MB xml file (over 300,000 "<"abc:ABCRecord">") into a mysql datatable via shell/terminal? The xml file itself has the following structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<abc:ABCData xmlns:abc="http://www.abc-example.com" xmlns:xyz="http:/www.xyz-example.com">
<abc:ABCHeader>
<abc:ContentDate>2015-08-15T09:03:29.379055+00:00</abc:ContentDate>
<abc:FileContent>PUBLISHED</abc:FileContent>
<abc:RecordCount>310598</abc:RecordCount>

 </abc:ABCHeader>
<abc:ABCRecords>
 <abc:ABCRecord>
 ....
</abc:ABCRecord>
</abc:ABCRecords>
</abc:ABCData>
```

How does the mysql table need to look like and what's the shell command? The goal is to have all the abc tagged content in the table. In addition, there will be a new zip file each day provided via a download link and it should update the table each day. The zip files are named after the following structure: "20150815-XYZ-concatenated-file.zip". In total there are over 300,000 "<"abc:Record">".

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MySQL's [LOAD XML INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html), a fast bulk import procedure (akin to the LOAD DATA INFILE query) with following steps:

1) Uncompress the zip file.

2) Transform raw xml using an [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to align to MySQL's needed format without attributes or nested nodes. Child elements must correspond to MySQL database table fields:

```
<row>
  <column1>data</column1>
  <column2>data</column2>
  <column3>data</column3>
  ...
</row>
```

For your above example:

```
<record>
  <ABC>5967007L</ABC>
  <Name>REGISTERENHETEN I Bornheim</Name>
  <Line1>Havnegata 48</Line1>
  <City>Bornheim</City>
  <Country>NO</Country>
</record>
```

3) Finally, save below query in a **.sql** file and call it with `source` command in shell/terminal:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Path\To\transformedFile.xml'
INTO TABLE person
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<record>';
```

A dedicated programming language (PHP, Python, Java, C#, VBA) would probably be best to handle above steps with a daily script scheduler (crontab, windows task scheduler, etc.).